# How do I override fetch conflicts, so that if git finds the same exact file, it doesn't give a conflict?

Tags: git, netbeans, centos

After looking through countless websites and many different stack over flow posts, I could not find the answer to what seems like a rather simple solution.

#### My setup

I develop locally on NetBeans but don't do any git operations through NetBeans except for fetching updates. Anytime I save/delete/create/etc on NetBeans, those changes automatically propagate to a remote Linux server. I then run all my git commands using the Linux command line on that remote server.

#### The problem and question

Since I did my original development on netbeans, some of the files that the git fetch operation pulls already exist in netbeans and therefore throws conflicts. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I need to be able to pull other developers updates into my netbeans and not receive these conflicts caused by my own files already existing. I previously used SVN and didn't have this problem because SVN didn't care, but now we switched to git and I have to resolve this.

### UPDATE

IT TURNS OUT THE ISSUE WAS DUE TO NETBEANS in windows having different line endings (/r/n) than when files are created in linux (/n). So a netbeans plugin called http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46829/change-line-endings-on-save converts all line endings to linux and solved the problem.

After this was resolved, another issue came up that basically tells me that the netbeans support for GIT isn't 100% complete. Basically if you try and pull in files that you already have in your netbeans working copy, GIT throws a conflict even if they are the same exact files with the same content with the same unix line endings. To solve this problem, I had to download a git commandline client for windows http://msysgit.github.io/ (because netbeans currently doesn't have support for stashes). And then just install the bash portion with unix line endings, and run git stash save "my changes". Then do the fetch & merge (or pull), then run git stash apply PATCHNAME. No conflicts. :-) Thanks! Mayur!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected and a desired behavior. Suppose you made change in function a in file b and didn't commit and maintained it in your local repository(your workspace). And say some other developer also made changes exactly in the same file and function but committed it into the git repository from where you pull his/her changes. In this case, git will try to use it's intelligence(merge algorithm) in the best possible manner to merge the code but if conflict is really ugly , it notifies the developer for a manual merge. THIS IS REQUIRED BEHAVIOR. How would git know what to keep ?

---

RESOLUTION AS WE WORKED OUT TOGETHER ON THIS :

It was the linux line endings (EOL) that were the culprit. Every git fetch on to the windows via netbeans IDE would introduce linux EOL which would conflict with end of line style and cause a merge conflict. The best thing to do here is commit as linux EOL when you commit from windows box.